# Unity LogitechSDK cannot detect my G29 Steering wheel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I try to develop a driving simulator, I started with G27 steering wheel and everything works fine with LogitechSDK in Unity. But when I switch to G29, the SDK seems cannot detect the steering wheel. But by using Unity default crossplatform control, I can see Unity take the input from G29 just fine. 
[No Connection from SDK Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JnR8.png)

[But Unity can detect disconnection and reconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIek0.png)

I can't understand what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve your problem but would just like to share my experience in case it helps.

About a year ago, I too tried to build a driving simulator in Unity using the G29. I was able to obtain input from the G29. Some steps I took were to ensure that the Logitech Gaming Software application was installed and running, and to set up the InputManager for the joystick (you'll need to map out the controls).

However, I was unable to get the force-feedback to work, due to a bug on Logitech's part (I managed to contact their tech support, who was also unable to solve it). I haven't since been following the news of whether they've managed to fix it, perhaps you'd know (: